# tests fail with Lock wait timeout exceeded after swicthing to InnoDB tables

Tags: mysql, django, unit-testing, innodb

I have a django 1.5 app that had been running with MySQL 5.1 and MyISAM tables. I upgraded to MySQL 5.5 and converted my tables to InnoDB and now my tests are failing with 'Lock wait timeout exceeded.' The app itself is working fine.

In my tests I load some tables from fixtures then fork off a python script that loads data to other tables. In that python script I call `get_or_create` and that's what fails. It's waiting for a lock on a table that the object I am getting or creating has a foreign key reference into (which is a table loaded from a fixture). I think I know what is happening - django runs the tests in a transaction and the external python script is running in its own MySQL connection from the test so it's in its own transaction. When the foreign key is checked that table is locked because the transaction is not committed.

I tried changing the `tx_isolation` from `REPEATABLE-READ` (what it was originally) to `READ-COMMITTED` and then `READ-UNCOMMITTED` with no change in the behavior.

Is there some way to get around this?

Comment: While it is possible to increase the timeout, it would be better to figure out how _not_ to sit waiting so long.

Comment: The wait would be forever since the test is running in a transaction that will not complete until the test is done. The forked off python script is running outside of that transaction. I've got around this by instantiating the external script as a class and running it within the test's transaction.

Comment: Use a programmatic way of dealing with your "long running transaction", not InnoDB's transactions.  How did you do it with MyISAM?

Comment: MyISAM doesn't support transactions, so this was not an issue there. I don't think you understand the situation. The tests run in a transaction. The test forks off an external script that fails because tables it needs to access are locked by the test's transaction. This in turn causes the test to fail. The only way around this (other then what I did) would be to get the tests to not run in a transaction.

Comment: Since they did not used to run in a transaction, they don't need to now.  Or is this a new feature you 'need'?  InnoDB can simulate no-transaction mode.

Comment: Django’s TestCase class wraps each test in a transaction. I have not figured out how to disable that. I've tried a few different ways, but none of them have worked.

Comment: Grrrrr... Yet another case of 3rd party software getting in the way.  Change `innodb_lock_wait_timeout`.

Comment: And complain to Django.